# Docker's aufs diff folder is growing huge in terms of size

Tags: docker, filesystems, docker-registry

I'm having problem with space usage of docker. I have

/var/lib/docker/aufs/diff/e20ed0ec78d30267e8cf855c6311b02089b6086ea149c21997a3e6cb9757ecd4/tmp/registry-dev/docker/registry/v2/blobs# du -sh

4.6G    .

can I find which container does this folder belong to? I have docker registry running but inside there I have

/var/lib/registry/docker/registry/v2/blobs# du -sh

465M    .

I'm suspecting docker upgrade (I used migrate tool https://docs.docker.com/engine/migration/ here) could have left it, or, I was building docker registry myself before, and moving to pre-compiled registry left this.

can I somehow check which container it belogs to? or maybe, does it belong to any?

Comment: what gives `docker ps -a |  grep e20ed0` ?

Comment: nothing at all..., do they correspond to container ID's?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and the [spotify/docker-gc](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc) fixed it. Clone it then follow "[Running as a Docker Image](https://github.com/spotify/docker-gc#running-as-a-docker-image)"

Answer (score 0):

The spotify/docker-gc is not going to fix it, but it make things to turn for the better much easier. The first thing you need to do is to stop doing commits on the same image. As I've realized, this is going to build up a huge diff-dependency. What I did is that I've committed all my running containers into different image names and tags, stopped and restarted the containers. After that, I've deleted the old images manually, then ran spotify/docker-gc. I've saved about 20% of disk space. If I ran spotify/docker-gc before the commits into new images, nothing happened.

If you use spotify/docker-gc, please do `DRY_RUN`.